# Обновлённые шаблоны модераторских сообщений требуют перевода

Tags: дефект, локализация, модерация, инструменты-модератора

На данный момент, шаблоны сообщений модераторов, пοказываемые модераторам на интернациональных сайтах SO, являются старыми/устаревшими. Это происходит потому, что код для шаблонов сообщений модераторов указывает, то что эти устаревшие версии будут показываться на интернациональных сайтах SO, до тех пор, пока текущие версии этих шаблонов (использованные на всех других сайтах) не будут переведены.

Обновлённые версии шаблонов сообщений модератора, будут доступны как отдельные строки в Transifex/Traducir, но они пока не переведены на Русский. Как только они будут переведены, разработчики смогут применить текущие/актуальные шаблоны сообщений модераторов на все интернациональные сайты.

Вот соответствующие ссылки Traducir:

- [consistently low quality questions over time](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16849)
- [question repetition](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16845)
- [sockpuppet upvoting](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16843)
- [targeted votes](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16851)
- [abusive to others](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16846) – похоже, что она единственная имеет перевод на данный момент.
- [revenge downvoting](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16844)
- [self-destruction of useful content](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16855)
- [using signatures or taglines](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16850)
- [excessive self-promotion](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16854)
- [excessive discussion in comments](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16847)
- [plagiarism](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17982)
- [something else...](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16853)

Спасибо за вашу помощь!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Have you been able to make any more progress with these translations?

Comment: I'm expecting to see the translations as completed after 6-8 more weeks.

Comment: Do you know should the html-comment sections be translated [here](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16846) or not?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Yes, those HTML comments should be translated as well – since they are guidance for the mods, who will be the ones using the templates (and replacing the HTML comments with the appropriate text).

Comment: Note: The commented-out English text in the "abusive to others" template should also probably be translated (since it's guidance to the mods about choosing from the options it provides). Likewise, the placeholder text in the "something else..." template (except for the variable names themselves) should be translated as well when that template gets translated, since it's guidance on what those placeholders should be replaced with.

Comment: What should we do in case we need to fix some typos in translations? Will just updating translations on traducir be enough, or anyone from staff have to do extra manual work?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I believe updating Traducir should be sufficient; once finalized there, I think the updated translations will be used the next time the site is built out.

Comment: So what's preventing us to accept the answer, tag question as [status-completed] and use newly translated sentences?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: I still need to confirm that the translations for the other languages are done before the updated mod message templates go live for all the international sites. But thanks to you and everyone in the community for getting these done for Russian! :)

Comment: Looks like instead of [16855](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16855) the another [string](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10486) is actually used. It's not clear for me should we translate it, or should the different string be used.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: The mod message templates currently shown on the international sites (including SOru) are the old/outdated versions, since the international sites don't currently use the updated strings (which are used on English SO and the rest of the SE network). Once the mod message templates have been translated for all the international sites, I can let the devs know that these updated mod message templates should be used on the international sites as well.

Comment: (You *could* translate [string #10486](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10486) in the meantime so that English text doesn't appear until then – but that string would no longer be used once we switch to the updated mod message templates anyway.)

Comment: So the new one for 10486 is 16855, right? It's a pity that availability of translations on one site depends on other sites.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все упомянутые строки переведены.